# Any online videos of any topology course taught using the book "Topology" by Munkres

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, online-resources

Are there any videos available on the Internet — for watching online or for download — of any (general) topology course taught using the book *Topology* ($2$nd ed.) by James R. Munkres?

If so, please give me the link(s). If not, can I get these of any individual or institution upon request?

Answer (score 10):

If you do a
Google search for
"[munkres topology video](https://www.google.com/search?q=munkres+topology+video)",
you get a number of hits.

This is the first,
with the title
"General Topology - YouTube":

https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpG_ISEhQ6z0Q5MaIvdn5tBJFWfp9fZtQ

Answer (score 3):

I found this one.
https://freevideolectures.com/course/3528/topology
Topology IIT Madras, by P. Veeramani
21 lectures in total.
Not sure if it is based on Munkres, but Topology is Topology.